# Why does a sphere get uniformly charged when placed at the center of a superconducting spherical shell?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, superconductivity, thought-experiment

Take a superconducting spherical shell.

Then place a spherical non-uniformly charged ball at its center.

Then I know that the spherical (non-uniformly charged) ball will get uniformly charged. **Why does it happen?**

Comment: "Then I know that the spherical ball will get uniformly charged." do you have a link for this "knowledge"

Comment: @annav: please look at [my question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/526977/in-the-laboratory-is-it-possible-to-make-a-spherical-ball-uniformly-charged?noredirect=1#comment1195224_526977)  and comment from S. Mc Grew

Comment: see this for charging balls https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-002-electromagnetic-field-theory-a-problem-solving-approach-spring-2008/textbook-contents/MITRES_6_002S08_chapter2.pdf

Comment: I think the superconducting part is just extraneous, to make the ball uniformly charged, not to charge it. To charge it you would have to use electrostatic methods, and as the link above states, it has been done and that was the way they studied electrostatics.

Comment: Thanks a million for your link...In my original problem, actually I want to make my "charged distribution over a sphere" uniformly charged? Please have a look at my edited question

Answer (score 0):

If the distribution is not uniform it means that there are some region in the sphere that is more charged than the rest. How would one go about deciding which place that is? Why is this one region more special than others? Since our system is completely **spherically symmetric**, this distribution breaks that symmetry with nothing causing it to break.

Comment: Thank you very much for your point. But I am a bit confused here. If there is no electric field inside a spherical shell, then why would the charges move and align themselves in a manner that makes the distribution uniform? What makes the charges move in a zero electric field?

Comment: "There is no electric field inside a conducting sphere" assumes that there are no additional charged bodies trapped inside the sphere. Once you do that, then those charges do create a local electric field. There is now no electric field inside the inner conducting sphere. Unless of course...